# How to get the previous URL after using window.history.back()?

Tags: javascript, html

Some context: the user searches in page A using some filters, then select some item to edit from the results which carries the user to page B to edit that item.

In page B there's a Back button, which should go to previous page (A) when clicking. The thing is that when going back I have to show the previous result of the search made in A **if** the user comes from page B (item editing), not from the menu or other page that redirects to A.

Doing **`window.history.back()`** in B, I get back to A and **the inputs are preserved**, so the only thing I would need is to check in the document ready if the user comes from the editing page or not, so I can decide to perform the search or not.

I've tried with `document.referrer` but it seems that it doesn't work when doing history.back() but just with hrefs.

I know I can use localStorage or save the inputs in the session to later retrieval, but **is there a way to access the previous URL consistently after using window.history.back()?**

Comment: @user4703663 Have you tried it just after using a history.back()? Go to your profile, put history.back() in the console, and when arriving this page again, try document.referrer, it doesn't return the URL of your profile.

Comment: That's right, the idea of `history.back()` is to work just like the Back button. When you use the Back button to return to a page, the page still has the same referrer it had before. Since a page may change its content depending on the referrer, it wouldn't make sense for the Back button to change the referrer.

Comment: @MichaelGeary I know, but I'd like to know if there a way of accessing the URL of the page I have just history.back() from.